# Что не так с digitalocean?

Tags: веб-программирование, администрирование, vps, digitalocean

Не могу войти в панель управления на сайте digitalocean.
Раньше вводил email(login) и пароль, и приходило смс, после чего я успешно заходил на сайт.
Сейчас смс не приходит, на всякий случай оператор Yota.
Все действия ведены верно и жду смс с кодом, а его нет.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? И как её решить?
Писал в поддержку там открывается ticket, но доступ к нему после того как войду на сайте wtf?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а backup code есть?

Comment: нет вроде бы, не помню

Comment: мне помогли, когда я им в твиттер написал. но у меня был другой вопрос.